# What is the best way to display a SQL table through PHP?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I've looked on Google, but I haven't been able to find the best, simplest way to display SQL tables through PHP.  I'm new at PHP and SQL, so I'm a bit confused.  I have this so far, but I'm not even sure how the rows work.  I just want to display the whole table.

```
<?php
$dbname = 'my_db';

if (!mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password')) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Table: {*}\n";
}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to show the table names or the contents of a table?  Also, side note, be _very_ careful here.  If you're "new to PHP and SQL" then there's a good chance you'll open up a SQL injection vulnerability somewhere in your code.  Giving users the names of all of your tables opens that vulnerability even wider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should only show you the table names in the specified database.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Table: {$row[0]}\n";
}
```

If you want to view the content of each table you will have to do something like this:

```
mysql_select_db($dbname);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    //echo "Table: {$row[0]}\n";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM $row[0]";
    $table = mysql_query($query);

    echo "<table>";
    while($content = mysql_fetch_array($table)){
            echo "<tr>";
        foreach($content as $key => $value){
            echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
        }
            echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you're looking for is `DESCRIBE` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en
/describe.html which will give you something like:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE City;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name       | char(35) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Country    | char(3)  | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| District   | char(20) | YES  | MUL |         |                |
| Population | int(11)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

If you replace this parte of your code

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Table: {*}\n";
}
```

by

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

you will undestand better what `$row` is set to.

**UPDATE**

On the other hand, if you're just trying to fetch all data you have in some table, the query you have to do is a `SELECT` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html which will be something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
```